# Alternative to scipy.optimize.curve_fit

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I'm trying to plot some visualisations with matplotlib, and in one of my functions, I check if waves are logarithmic. This is my current working version:

```
import numpy as np
def is_logarithmic(waves):

    def expfunc(x, a, b, c):
        return a*np.exp(b*x) + c

    wcopy = list(waves)
    wcopy.sort()

    # If the ratio of x-max : x-min < 10, don't use a logarithmic scale
    # (at least in matplotlib)
    if (wcopy[-1] / wcopy[0]) < 10:
        return False

    # Take a guess at whether it is logarithmic by seeing how well the x-scale
    # fits an exponential curve
    diffs = []
    for ii in range(len(wcopy) - 1):
        diffs.append(wcopy[ii + 1] - wcopy[ii])

    # Fit the diffs to an exponential curve
    x = np.arange(len(wcopy)-1)
    try:
        popt, pcov = curve_fit(expfunc, x, diffs)
    except Exception as e:
        print e
        popt = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
        pcov = np.inf

    # If a > 0.5 and covsum < 1000.0
    # use a logarithmic scale.
    if type(pcov) == float:
        # It's probably np.inf
        covsum = pcov
    else:
        covsum = pcov.diagonal().sum()
    res = (covsum < 1000.0) & (popt[0] > 0.5)
    return res
```

I'm trying to find an alternative to scipy's `curve_fit()`, because I don't want to install such a big library just to use that one function. Is there something else I can use, or a combination of other functions from using ideally just numpy and matplotlib, to get a similar result?

Comment: Well, `curve_fit` uses the [Levenberg-Marquardt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm) algorithm to do the minimization of errors. You can always implement it yourself.

Comment: Unless you are working with embedded systems, `46 MB` (installed on linux) for scipy is not that much. Matplotlib is `72 MB` in comparison.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Numpy can do linear (`numpy.linalg.lstsq`) and polynomial fits (`numpy.polyfit`). In general you need scipy for fitting to functions you define yourself (scipy uses the fortran minpack while numpy is built only with C).

However, for your example, you could use a similar approach to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433486/how-to-do-exponential-and-logarithmic-curve-fitting-in-python-i-found-only-poly) question to fit an exp. Basically, take the logatithm of both sides of the equation and use `numpy.polyfit`.

Comment: Taking the `log` of both sides will not work in this case because of the constant term `c` in the `a*np.exp(b*x) + c`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `lmfit.models` library which has a lot of predefined models.

https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/

https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/builtin_models.html#exponential-and-power-law-models

It also supports custom functions.

Comment: The goal of the questioner is to avoid installing a large library like scipy for a singular function. lmfit doesn't really fulfill that requirement, since it requires scipy as a dependency.