# Python - Find Weights Through Least Square Minimization

Tags: python, python-3.x, least-squares, minimization

I have an array of data from a function that resemble loosely a sine wave which were obtained through filtering, let's call them A[ ]. They are not smooth or scaled correctly. In another array I have data from a "perfect" sine wave, generated in python through the sin function, let's call them B[ ].

What I want to do in Python is to find the correct array of weights W[ ] so my first data can be "fitted" to the second, in such a way the least square error is minimized

E = sum(A[ ]-W[ ]*B[ ])^2

Practically I want to find the weights so to scale the values of A correctly. My problem is that the standard least square error optimization procedure in Python is the opposite one. How can I do that?

Comment: Does [Least square method in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43616993/least-square-method-in-python) provide you with the approach?

Comment: @itprorh66 No as I said in my question this method does the opposite of what I want.  It fits a curve on data and not the other way around.

Comment: Could you provide an example of A[] and B[]?  What approaches have you tried?