# Can I make a logarithmic regression on sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

I don't know if "logarithmic regression" is the right term, I need to fit a curve on my data, like a polynomial curve but going flat on the end.

Here is an image, the blue curve is what I have (2nd order polynomial regression) and the magenta curve is what I need.

[image]

I have search a lot and can't find that, only linear regression, polynomial regression, but no logarithmic regression on sklearn. I need to plot the curve and then make predictions with that regression.

**EDIT**

Here is the data for the plot image that I posted:

```
x,y
670,75
707,46
565,47
342,77
433,73
472,46
569,52
611,60
616,63
493,67
572,11
745,12
483,75
637,75
218,251
444,72
305,75
746,64
444,98
342,117
272,85
128,275
500,75
654,65
241,150
217,150
426,131
155,153
841,66
737,70
722,70
754,60
664,60
688,60
796,55
799,62
229,150
232,95
116,480
340,49
501,65
```

Comment: Can you post some sample data (or code to generate example data)? Might you be able to do a transform on the underlying data and then fit your model?

Comment: There, I added the data

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to fit the data with a function like y = a * exp(-b * (x - c)) + d.

I am not sure if sklearn can do it. But you can use scipy.optimize.curve_fit() to fit your data with whatever the function you define.([scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html)):

For your case, I experimented with your data and here is the result:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

my_data = np.genfromtxt('yourdata.csv', delimiter=',')
my_data = my_data[my_data[:,0].argsort()]
xdata = my_data[:,0].transpose()
ydata = my_data[:,1].transpose()

# define a function for fitting
def func(x, a, b, c, d):
    return a * np.exp(-b * (x - c)) + d

init_vals = [50, 0, 90, 63]
# fit your data and getting fit parameters
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata, p0=init_vals, bounds=([0, 0, 90, 0], [1000, 0.1, 200, 200]))
# predict new data based on your fit
y_pred = func(200, *popt)
print(y_pred)

plt.plot(xdata, ydata, 'bo', label='data')
plt.plot(xdata, func(xdata, *popt), '-', label='fit')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: plot from the code above]

I found that the initial value for `b` is critical for fitting. I estimated a small range for it and then fit the data.

If you have no priori knowledge of the relationship between `x` and `y`, you can use the regression methods provided by sklearn, like linear regression, Kernel ridge regression (KRR), Nearest Neighbors Regression, Gaussian Process Regression etc. to fit nonlinear data. [Find the documentation here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/supervised_learning.html)

Comment: Yeah I think that's it, thanks I will try it. By the way; is there a scipy method to give it data and make it decide what model use? Automatically make lineal, polynomial, logarithmic, etc, check what's best and apply that model? Or I have to do it manually??

Comment: @AlvaroHernandorena I don't think there is a method to do it automatically. But you can write a script by yourself by defining a few functions and then follow the codes in my answers.

Comment: tnx for ur answer, I ended up doing that, the curve_fit with custom func, it didn't work at first it just keep says that it couldn't find the parameters, until I started to play with the bounds, and after a while I understood that 'a + d' is y when x = 0, and 'b' also is important so I set bounds using relations from the data (I found max and min values of x and y on the data and use that; a = 3*maxX, b = 10*maxX , c = minY *3 ) and now is working perfectly. thank you again!

Comment: Is there something like logarithmic transformation, like  polynomial features?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54949969/multivariate-logarithmic-regression-with-python

Comment: This could be improved by plotting `y_pred` for x-values beyond those that happen to exist in `xdata`. e.g. 1000 predicted datapoints: `x_pred =  np.linspace(min(xdata), max(xdata), num=1000); y_pred = func(x_pred, *popt); plt.plot(x_pred, y_pred, '-', label='fit')`

Answer (score 5):

You are looking at [exponentially distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) data.

You can transform your y-variable by log and then use linear regression. This works because large values of y are compressed more than smaller values.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import expon

x = np.linspace(1, 10, 10)
y = np.array([30, 20, 12, 8, 7, 4, 3, 2, 2, 1])
y_fit = expon.pdf(x, scale=2)*100

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.scatter(x, y)
ax.plot(x, y_fit)
ax.set_ylabel('y (blue)')
ax.grid(True)

ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.scatter(x, np.log(y), color='red')
ax2.set_ylabel('log(y) (red)')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: ok, so no sklearn needed? but how do I do a prediction based on that?

Comment: You can still use scikit-learn `LinearRegression` for the regression. Or you can check out the [statsmodels](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/statsmodels) library.

Say you want to make a prediction yhat = alpha+beta*x0. You would have to transform yhat back into your space, i.e. `np.exp(yhat)`

Comment: I just found this [great explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433486/how-to-do-exponential-and-logarithmic-curve-fitting-in-python-i-found-only-poly).

Comment: Ok so I think I understand. Take my data and make it linear by applying log function, then make a lineal regression on that transformed data, predict , and finally transform predicted value applying exp function. Is that right??

Comment: That's correct. You should also plot the log-transformed data to see if the fit is truly linear. You might still need to use poly fit but the fit will be much better than with the original data.

Answer (score 4):

To use sklearn, you can first remodel your case `y = Aexp(-BX)` to `ln(Y) = ln(A) - BX`, and then use LinearRegressor to train and fit your data.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

### Read Data
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

### Prepare X, Y & ln(Y)
X = df.sort_values(by=['x']).loc[:, 'x':'x']
Y = df.sort_values(by=['x']).loc[:, 'y':'y']
ln_Y = np.log(Y)

### Use the relation ln(Y) = ln(A) - BX to fit X to ln(Y)
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
exp_reg = LinearRegression()
exp_reg.fit(X, ln_Y)
#### You can introduce weights as well to apply more bias to the smaller X values, 
#### I am transforming X arbitrarily to apply higher arbitrary weights to smaller X values
exp_reg_weighted = LinearRegression()
exp_reg_weighted.fit(X, ln_Y, sample_weight=np.array(1/((X - 100).values**2)).reshape(-1))

### Get predicted values of Y
Y_pred = np.exp(exp_reg.predict(X))
Y_pred_weighted = np.exp(exp_reg_weighted.predict(X))

### Plot
plt.scatter(X, Y)
plt.plot(X, Y_pred, label='Default')
plt.plot(X, Y_pred_weighted, label='Weighted')
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: For me, I change this line, it worked fine:  `exp_reg_weighted.fit(X, ln_Y, sample_weight=np.array(1/((X - 100)**2)).reshape(-1)) `