# Exponential curve fitting a data set

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, curve-fitting, exponential

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

points = np.array([
 (333, 195.3267),
 (500, 223.0235),
 (1000, 264.5914),
 (2000, 294.8728),
 (5000, 328.3523),
 (10000, 345.4688)
])

# get x and y vectors
x = points[:,0]
y = points[:,1]
```

What would be my next steps in order to create an exponential curve fit the graph?

Comment: [How to do exponential and logarithmic curve fitting in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433486/how-to-do-exponential-and-logarithmic-curve-fitting-in-python-i-found-only-poly)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do exponential and logarithmic curve fitting in Python? I found only polynomial fitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433486/how-to-do-exponential-and-logarithmic-curve-fitting-in-python-i-found-only-poly)

Answer (score 1):

Here is  an example of fitting the data to a logarithmic quadratic equation that fits the data somewhat better than an exponential, and plots the fitted curve against a scatterplot of the raw data. The code is not optimal, for example it repeatedly takes the log of X rather than just doing it one time. The log(x) data can be more efficiently fit by directly using a linear fitting method as well, however here you can replace the fitted equation with an exponential much more easily with less code changes.

```
import numpy
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

points = numpy.array([(333, 195.3267), (500, 223.0235), (1000, 264.5914), (2000, 294.8728
), (5000, 328.3523), (10000, 345.4688)])
# get x and y vectors
xData = points[:,0]
yData = points[:,1]

# function to be fitted
def LogQuadratic(x, a, b, c):
    return a + b*numpy.log(x) + c*numpy.power(numpy.log(x), 2.0)


# some initial parameter values
initialParameters = numpy.array([1.0, 1.0, 1.0])

fittedParameters, pcov = curve_fit(LogQuadratic, xData, yData, initialParameters)

# values for display of fitted function
a, b, c = fittedParameters

# for plotting the fitting results
xPlotData = numpy.linspace(min(xData), max(xData), 50)
y_plot = LogQuadratic(xPlotData, a, b, c)

plt.plot(xData, yData, 'D') # plot the raw data as a scatterplot
plt.plot(xPlotData, y_plot) # plot the equation using the fitted parameters
plt.show()

print('fitted parameters:', fittedParameters)
```