# Fitted Exponential Curve Error

Tags: python, curve-fitting, exponential

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def func(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.exp(-b * x) + c

x =  [333,500,1000,2000,5000,10000]

y = [195.3267, 233.0235, 264.5914,294.8728, 328.3523,345.4688]

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y, 'ko', label="Original Noised Data")
plt.plot(x, func(x, *popt), 'r-', label="Fitted Curve")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

> Error: 
>   C:\Users\Aidan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py:794:
>   OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated
>   category=OptimizeWarning)
>
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>        14 plt.figure()
>        15 plt.plot(x, y, 'ko', label="Original Noised Data")
>   ---> 16 plt.plot(x, func(x, *popt), 'r-', label="Fitted Curve")
>        17 plt.legend()
>        18 plt.show()
>
> in func(x, a, b, c)
>         4 
>         5 def func(x, a, b, c):
>   ----> 6     return a * np.exp(-b * x) + c
>         7 
>         8 x =  [333,500,1000,2000,5000,10000]
>
> TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

For some reason I am not able to get a curve fit based on my data. I am following the exponential example from here: [How to do exponential and logarithmic curve fitting in Python? I found only polynomial fitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433486/how-to-do-exponential-and-logarithmic-curve-fitting-in-python-i-found-only-poly)

But I am using an two arrays rather than made up random data. I am new to python!

Comment: wrap x and y with np.array, like x = np.array(x), y= np.array(y)

Comment: @HongyuWang I get this error now:

Comment: ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-9636549533b2> in <module>()
      6     return a * np.exp(-b * x) + c
      7 
----> 8 x =   np.array(333,500,1000,2000,5000,10000)
      9 
     10 y =  np.array(195.3267, 233.0235, 264.5914,294.8728, 328.3523,345.4688)

ValueError: only 2 non-keyword arguments accepted

Comment: no, do x = np.array([333,500,1000,2000,5000,10000]), y = np.array([...])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code.

- You use lists instead of `numpy.ndarray`: the `numpy` and `scipy` routines are meant to work with `numpy.ndarray` and they use them internally. You should use them as well.
- You are likely to get overflow issues with your data and your function, e.g. `np.exp(-1000)` is already approximated to zero in Python3
- You are trying to fit a function that it is unlikely to fit your data. It looks more like an exponential recovery than a decay.

The following code tentatively address all these issues:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def func(x, a, b, c):
    return a * (1 - np.exp(-b * x)) + c

x =  np.array([333.0,500.0,1000.0,2000.0,5000.0,10000.0]) / 1000
y = np.array([195.3267, 233.0235, 264.5914,294.8728, 328.3523,345.4688]) / 10

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y)
print(popt)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y, 'ko', label="Original Noised Data")
plt.plot(x, func(x, *popt), 'r-', label="Fitted Curve")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: did you divide by 1000 and 10 to change the scale?

Comment: is there a way to make it look less blocky it looks like a bunch of tangent lines rather then a curve

Comment: Yes. That way you will avoid overflow errors. As for the plotting issues, you get to plot what you ask for: if you want the function to look "less blocky", you should have more support points. One way of doing that is to define a new array for the independent variable, e.g. `x2 = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)` and use that for plotting, e.g. `plt.plot(x2, func(x2, *popt))`

Comment: if this answer solved your issues, perhaps you should consider accepting it as *best answer* ;-)

Comment: how do i do that LOL

Comment: check this out: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Why did we divide those 2 numbers to avoid overflow errors. trying to understand in better detail

Comment: what do you mean?