# How to fit a specific exponential function with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting

I'm trying to fit a series of data to a exponential equation, I've found some great answer here: [How to do exponential and logarithmic curve fitting in Python? I found only polynomial fitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433486/how-to-do-exponential-and-logarithmic-curve-fitting-in-python-i-found-only-poly) But it didn't contain the step forward that I need for this question.

I'm trying to fit *y* and *x* against a equation: *y* = *-Ae*<sup>*Bx*</sup> + *A*. The final *A* has proven to be a big trouble and I don't know how to transform the equation like *log(y)* = *log(A)* + *Bx* as if the final A was not there.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you want A twice in that equation?

Comment: Also, absorb the second A into the log on the left hand side.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Its unknown, hence can’t be calculated

Comment: Did you mean y=-Ae^Bx + C? Or is C == A, and that's not a typo?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes that is not a typo, the original equation is *y/A* = *-e^(Bx)* + 1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always just use `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` as long as your equation isn't too crazy:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as sio

def f(x, A, B):
    return -A*np.exp(B*x) + A

A = 2
B = 1
x = np.linspace(0,1)

y = f(x, A, B)
scale = (max(y) - min(y))*.10
noise = np.random.normal(size=x.size)*scale
y += noise

fit = sio.curve_fit(f, x, y)

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.plot(x, f(x, *fit[0]))
plt.show()
```

This produces:

[image]

Comment: Interesting and nice explanation, I'll try it out.

Comment: Worked! I just needed to flip B to negative because it doesn't deal with negative numbers apparently.

Comment: @RockyLi Great, glad to hear it. And if you're ever bored and looking for some math to do, you may be able to derive an analytical expression for the fit using the [least-squares approach](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFitting.html). There's a [well-known closed form equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFittingExponential.html) for the fit of the standard exponential form `y = A*e**(B*x)`