# Problem while fitting a set of data points to arbitrary curve with Scipy

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy

I have a set of data points which, according to the model I want to implement, could be modelled with a certain curve (in this case, a product between an exponential and a complementary error function).

For fitting these data into such a curve, I tried:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy import special

x_fit = np.linspace(0,1,1000)
def fitted_function(x_fit, c, d, S):
    return c*np.exp(((S*d/2)**2)-x_fit*d)*special.erfc(S*d/2-x_fit/S)
FitParameters, FitCovariance = curve_fit(fitted_function, x_data, y_data, maxfev = 100000)
```

It does not give me any particular error, but the result of the fitting is evidently wrong. I strongly suspect that it has to do with the the part `x_fit/S`, where the fitting parameter `S` appears as a denominator.

For example, I encounter the same problem while fitting a simple exponential: if I define the fitting curve with

```
    return a*np.exp(-x_fit/b)
```

with `a`, `b` fitting parameters; since the fitting parameter `b` appears as a denominator, I find the same problem (i.e. the resulting fitted curve is a horizontal line for some reason).
For the case of a simple exponential I can simple bypass this by doing

```
    return a*np.exp(-b*x_fit)
```

so that `b` is not a denominator anymore and the fitted curve is really an exponential curve. For my current case, instead, I cannot do this since `S` appears ad a numerator and a denominator in different part of the expression.
Any ideas? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried giving reasonable initial guesses for the parameters (at least the correct order of magnitude) to `curve_fit`, using the `p0` argument?

Comment: No, I didn't, but effectively it works now! Thank you!

Comment: a non linear fitting as in your case is really sensitive to the initial guess, check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433486/how-to-do-exponential-and-logarithmic-curve-fitting-in-python-i-found-only-poly)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do exponential and logarithmic curve fitting in Python? I found only polynomial fitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433486/how-to-do-exponential-and-logarithmic-curve-fitting-in-python-i-found-only-poly)