# How to fit exponential function with python

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting

I am new to python and I am trying to learn how to plot and fit data.
I have an empeirical formula for describing the function y(x)
and i want to fit it to an exponential of the form : y = a* x ^ b

I am using numpy.arrays but i am not sure  numpy.polyfit is usefull here because i do not want to fit with high order polynomials, neither exponentials of the form : y = a * e ^ (b*x).

Can you please suggest a way to do this?

my function is this one, here written as y (E_n):

```
E_n = np.linspace(1, 10**6, 10**6)
y= 0.018*(E_n**(-2.7)) * (1/(1+(2.77*cos(45)*E_n/115)) + 0.367/(1+(1.18*cos(45)*E_n/850)))
```

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do exponential and logarithmic curve fitting in Python? I found only polynomial fitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433486/how-to-do-exponential-and-logarithmic-curve-fitting-in-python-i-found-only-poly)

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [`scipy.optimize.curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html). Define a function of the form you desire, pass it to the function. Read the linked documentation well. In many cases, you may need to pass chosen initial values for the parameters. `curve_fit` takes all of them to be `1` by default, and this might not yield desirable results.

Comment: hey, i tried using curve_fit but the parameters it gives me are 2 dimensional for some reason. i think it has something to do with raising the array to a power.