# Why scipy curve_fit to a power law in a log log scale gives a wrong fit?

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, loglog

I am trying to **fit a power law to some data following a power law with noise, displayed in a log-log scale**:

[image]

The fit with scipy curve_fit is the orange line and the red line is the noiseless power law.

Here is the code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


def powerFit(x, A, B):
    return A * x**(-B)   

x = np.logspace(np.log10(1),np.log10(1e5),30)
A = 1
B = 2

np.random.seed(1)

y_noise = np.random.normal(1, 0.2, size=x.size)

y = powerFit(x, A, B) * y_noise

plt.plot(x, y, 'o')
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')

popt, pcov = curve_fit(powerFit, x, y, p0 = [A, B]) 
perr = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))

residuals = y - powerFit(x, *popt)
ss_res = np.sum(residuals**2)
ss_tot = np.sum((y-np.mean(y))**2)
r_squared = 1 - (ss_res / ss_tot)

plt.plot(x, powerFit(x, *popt),
        label = 'fit: A*x**(-B)\n   A=%.1e +- %.0e\n   B=%.1e +- %.0e\n   R2 = %.2f' %tuple(np.concatenate(( np.array([popt, perr]).T.flatten(), [r_squared]) ))) 

plt.plot(x, powerFit(x, A, B), 'r--', label = 'A = %d, B = %d'%(A,B))

plt.legend()
plt.savefig("fig.png", dpi = 300)
```

**I do not understand what is happening with the fitted power law. Why does it look wrong? How could I solve this?**

*Note:* I know you could also fit the power law plotting log(y) vs log(x). But according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3433503/12131616), it seems curve_fit should also manage to do it right directly. So my question is **if it is possible to do a power law fit in a log log scale without log transforming**. I am interested in avoiding the log-log transformation because it is not possible to apply to any fit (consider for example the fit to y = A*x**(-Bx) ).

Comment: Exponential curve fitting is prone to several problems - small changes in the exponent cause massive changes in the function result, and you can also easily cause numpy array overflows that may or may not be silent. In general, it is better to log-transform your input data and do a linear fit with those.

Comment: @Mr.T Actually this question comes because I have an histogram with log bins and I wanted to fit it to a different function. But I am having similar problems to this power law fit. And I think I can't just transform the other fit in terms of log(y) vs log(x).

Comment: How about asking then the actual question?

Comment: @Mr.T It is actually the same question: how to fit data equally weighted in log log scales without log-transforming.